# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d not working

Tags: .htaccess

I have seen several other threads about this but for some reason in my specific case the solutions are not working.

Here is the .htaccess

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
Options +FollowSymLinks -Multiviews -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1
```

The desired effect is that index.php will load what ever page is requested in the GET (/events-diary = index.php?page=events-diary) & that works fine.

However I have some REAL directories which need to be accessible for example /admin/

The above .htaccess works perfectly fine as desired on my home computer MAMP, it works perfectly fine on my Amazon Micro, **it will not work on the deployment server ipage.com**

When you enter /admin it will redirect to the root index. When you type /admin/index.php it works, but you have to specify the index.php

I cant figure out when it seems to be ignoring the !-d

UPDATE:

index.php contains the following PHP

```
if(!isset($_GET['page'])){
    header("Location: home");
    exit;
}
$line=page_content($_GET['page']);
```

note that this functions fine on the other 2 servers, i dont see why it would behave differently on the 3rd.

Comment: What happens when you enter: `example.com/admin/` in the browser?

Comment: it redirects to example.com/home which is index.php?page=home

Comment: Try to use `-MultiViews` with uppercase `V`.

Comment: @Croises LOL amazingly it worked! Write an answer ill accept you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
```

With `-MultiViews` with uppercase `V`.
For Apache, in some cases upper/lower case are very important

Comment: Thanks for the answer & a really great tip for the future. I think we all copy & paste a standard .htaccess & modify it, but we copy & paste bad practice without knowing a golden tip like this :-)

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked out. I must say that I do not find very natural the way Apache handles this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different set of rewrite rules that might work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

Are you trying to route things to /admin/index.php?  If so, you could create a copy of your .htaccess, upload it to the /admin directory and set the RewriteBase to /admin.

or, if you wanted to turn the rewrite engine off in your /admin directory, you could create an .htacess file that contains:

```
RewriteEngine off
```

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to post these suggestions in comment so resorting to an answer.

Try this rule:

```
ErrorDocument 404 default
ErrorDocument 403 default
DirectorySlash On
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
Options +FollowSymLinks -Multiviews -Indexes

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/ !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```